# How to deal with sigma point leading to impossible measure with Unscented Kalman filter?

Tags: kalman-filter

Suppose I want to track an object and the sensor is a camera. Suppose the uncertainty is so big that sigma points gets behind the camera, so that they are not observable from the sensor, and not projectable to the measurement space... How should one deal with such case ?

Comment: I retracted my previous answer, but I still think that just treating this as a missing measurement might help. If the variance is so large, you might as well ignore this point.

Comment: What is "usncented"?

Comment: It is a typo...

Comment: the sigma points is actually not measurement, but some kind of ampling around the estimated state, that are mapped into measure space, then the update is done in measure space https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kalman_filter#Unscented_Kalman_filter

Comment: yes, I mean treat this object measurement as a missing measurement.